# Not Getting Max and Min Value for Money String Array

Tags: php, arrays, max, min

This is my array

```
Array ( [0] => $30.00 [1] => $200.00 [2] => $138.00 [3] => $100.00 [4] => $30.00 
[5]=>$30.00 [6] => $30.00 )
```

Trying to get the max and min value from this array

```
echo $maxprice = max($list);
echo $minprice = min($list);
```

I get $30.00 for max and $100.00 for min

I am guessing this is due to the values are in money string.

Can someone please tell me how I could get the real max and min for this array? Is this really due to money string?

Thanks in advance

***Note***
This array is stripped down from a multidimensional array. If it was normal array, it would be straightforward

Comment: Have you tried using non-money values?

Comment: @arxanas, this array is stripped from a multidimensional array. Non-money values work, but I am having issues with this money string format

Comment: Since the "money values" are not "numeric" strings, string comparison is done when finding the min/max (c.f. numeric comparison).  This sorts them in the order `$100.00, $138.00, $200.00, $30.00, $30.00, $30.00, $30.00` (from min to max).  To get the behaviour that you're looking for, they need to be actually numeric values or at least numeric strings (i.e. with no `$`). There are myriad ways of getting numeric strings from your array.

Comment: @salathe Thanks! I really thought there's alot of codes involved in it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use decimal values (without the "$") in your array.  The dollar sign should only be applied when outputting to display.

To get the string converted to floats, you can just `array_walk()` the array.

If on PHP 5.3 or greater, I like to use closures like this

```
array_walk($array, function (&$value, $key) {
   $value = (float)ltrim($value, '$');
});
```

If in older version of PHP, you would need to define a separate function and call the function in array_walk like this

```
array_walk($array, 'strip_dollar_signs');

function strip_dollar_signs (&$value, $key) {
    $value = (float)ltrim($value, '$');
}
```

Then just sort your array as you typically would

```
sort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

Comment: I stored values into this array from a multidimensional array

Comment: could you let me know how to convert this into number number?

Comment: Well, is your array actually string values? (i.e. `"$30.00"` not `$30.00`)

Comment: @jsmoove88 see revised answer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the '$' sign to make sure php treats the values as numbers

Comment: I stored values into this array from a multidimensional array. Could you know let me know how to convert it to normal numbers?

Comment: this definitely makes me look silly haha.. I really thought you would need to go through steps to convert money string to a number. Didn't expect it to be that easy -_-

Answer (score 1):

consider storing numeric values only, unless you work with more than one currency.
this code should get you minimum and maximum

```
$copy = $list;
foreach($copy as $key=>$value)$copy[$key] = str_replace('$', '', $value);

echo $maxprice = max($copy);
echo $minprice = min($copy);
```